# Будет ли Яндекс индексировать такие адреса

Tags: индексация, robots.txt, яндекс-поиск

Будет ли Яндекс индексировать такие адреса `index.php?id=1`, `index.php?id=2` и т.д., если их добавить в `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс будет их индексировать, но для скорейшего результата, лучше создайте `sitemap`, и туда их впишите, у файла `robots.txt` немного другая направленность.

И про внутреннюю перелинковку не забудьте, поисковики это любят.

Comment: @shilgen, можно поподробнее про внутреннюю перелинковку

Comment: на странице index.php?id=1 желательно иметь ссылку на страницу index.php?id=2 например в блоке "следующий пользователь", или "следующая статья", "рекомендуемая статья", "с этим товаром покупают" .... думаю общая логика понятна, так пользователи дольше удерживаются на сайте, больше покупают, ....